# How to fix error with Amazon Product API in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-product-api

I'm using the product advertising API from Amazon through the **python-amazon-simple-product-api** module to get product information like title, images and so on. It works OK when I start the server running the code, but after some time it stops working and I get an error that I'm not able to identify and solve.

If I restart the server it starts working, but it fails again after some time. I've tried changing the IP from the server, to check if my IP was blocked. But that wasn't the case. I'm not getting a clear error from the API, so I can't figure out how to solve the issue.

Also, I make sure that the ASIN is correct, so that not the problem.

Do you have any idea?

Here is my code:

```
region_options = bottlenose.api.SERVICE_DOMAINS.keys()
amazon = AmazonAPI(key, secret, tag, region='ES', MaxQPS=0.9, Timeout=6)
product = amazon.lookup(ItemId=asin)
```

And here is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/androizz_test/scrapers/scraper_amazon.py", line 51, in amazonGetData
    product = amazon.lookup(ItemId=c)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/amazon/api.py", line 174, in lookup
    response = self.api.ItemLookup(ResponseGroup=ResponseGroup, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/bottlenose/api.py", line 274, in __call__
    {'api_url': api_url, 'cache_url': cache_url})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/bottlenose/api.py", line 235, in _call_api
    return urllib2.urlopen(api_request, timeout=self.Timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 163, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 466, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 484, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1297, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1254, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1107, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1147, in _send_request
    self.putheader(hdr, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1083, in putheader
    if _is_illegal_header_value(values[i]):
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you check the value of asin, and make sure it is always valid?

Comment: Yes, I'm already doing it. The code I posted here is a reduced version of my current code. I can ensure that when I'm getting the error the ASIN is valid since I'm writing it on my log. Thanks!

Comment: How many requests are you performing before you get an empty response?

Comment: About 3 or 4 requests, then it fails every time until I restart the server. But if it was a requests limitation it should continue failing after restarting the server, right?

Comment: how are you getting asin from? Are you sure asin is valid everytime, and it is same or constant?

Comment: I'm getting the ASIN directly from the URL of the product, so it can be different every time depending on the product I want to check. Also, I'm sure the ASIN is valid for various reasons: the same product works correctly when I start the server and fails after some requests, sending a valid ASIN manually also fails and finally, I'm logging the errors and ASIN codes, so I've checked them manually and they are correct. Thanks!

Comment: What if you just use something like requests (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to make somethings equivalent to amazon.lookup and try that

Comment: That's my last option, but first I would like to know if there's any solution for this issue, since is more convenient for me using this module. Anyway, if I can't solve the problem I will use some other method like the one you said.

Comment: The amazon server is rejecting your requests for sure, since you are getting empty responses, maybe try wireshark or some packet sniffing tool to see what responses are you getting. If there is a way to get status code for your lookup . try that too

Comment: I have tried accessing the API directly with **requests** and it works correctly while using the API module doesn't, so I continue thinking that should be something related with the module I'm using. Don't you think?

Comment: Yes, for now you can continue working with requests, and maybe raise a bug with the api developers